# CSV Export from DataGrid - Wrong Rows

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid, export-to-csv

How can I export my datagrid to CSV correctly? Why are the Rows in different columns?

ExportToCsv function return:

> Column Headers:
>
> "SR #;8D Report Requested;Status (ASSIST);In R&D;BTQ NUMBER;Priority;Target Date;Implementation Date;Status (BTQ)"
>
> Rows: WRONG!
>
> "1-3271406718;yes;yes;BTQ00153254;6 - Enhancement;22.02.2014;09.09.2014 ;COMPLETED;Eng. wait"

How it should be:

> Column Headers:
>
> "SR #;8D Report Requested;Status (ASSIST);In R&D;BTQ NUMBER;Priority;Target Date;Implementation Date;Status (BTQ)"
>
> Rows:
>
> "1-3271406718;yes;Eng. wait;yes;BTQ00153254;6 - Enhancement;22.02.2014;09.09.2014 ;COMPLETED"

here my code:

```
                string CsvFpath = saveDLG.FileName;
                StreamWriter csvFileWriter = new StreamWriter(CsvFpath, false);
                string columnHeaderText = "";
                int countColumn = dgvView.Columns.Count - 1;
                if (countColumn >= 0)
                {
                    columnHeaderText = (dgvView.Columns[0].Header).ToString();
                }
                //Writing column headers
                for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
                {
                    columnHeaderText = columnHeaderText + ';' + (dgvView.Columns[i].Header).ToString();
                }
                csvFileWriter.WriteLine(columnHeaderText);

                // Writing values row by row
                for (int i = 0; i <= dgvView.Items.Count - 2; i++)
                {
                    string dataFromGrid = "";
                    for (int j = 0; j <= dgvView.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == 0)
                        {
                            dataFromGrid = ((DataRowView)dgvView.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[j].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ';' + ((DataRowView)dgvView.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[j].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    csvFileWriter.WriteLine(dataFromGrid);
                }
                csvFileWriter.Flush();
                csvFileWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Please actually provide your csv examples as text (that is, what is produced by your code) rather than Excel's interpretation of that file, and include it with the question rather than link to images.

Comment: Yes, much better. I am not a C# programmer so can't actually give you an answer, but when discussing csv you need to stick to text format because opening in Excel hides the separators (eg ; or ,) and makes other interpretations when it opens the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with Linq. It's simpler and easy to read:

```
    public string DataGridToCSV(string delimiter = ";")
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var headers = myDataGridView.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, headers.Select(column => "\"" + column.HeaderText + "\"").ToArray()));

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            var cells = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, cells.Select(cell => "\"" + cell.Value + "\"").ToArray()));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Just save the String as `*.csv` File and you're done.